# The set $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}, x^2 \leq 25\}$ is equal to $\{0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 5\}.$ Why is that so?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I encountered this statement as a multiple choice question in a test. My answer was $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb Z, x \leq 5\text{ or }x \geq -5\}.$ But as seen in the title, the correct answer is $\{0, \pm 1,  \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 5 \}?$

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Well they are the same ,two different forms of writing them

Comment: Do I miss something or is her answer also correct? EDIT: It should be an "and" not an "or" in the statement.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore but I ended up getting the question wrong in the test. Do you think you know why?

Comment: Note that the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ can be typeset by `\mathbb{Z}`.

Comment: @Maria instead of or you may want to use 'and' that might be the msitake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the use of "or". Note that $x=7$ satisfies the condition that "$x\geq -5\textbf{ or } x\leq 5$", as $7\geq 5$. When we say "or" we generally mean that either one or both of the conditions is satisfied.

If you had instead written $S=\{ x| x\geq -5 \text{ and } x\leq 5\}$ then any element $z\in S$ would satisfy both $z\geq -5$ and $z\leq 5$ simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!